# Add action to button from ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller

I have a problem adding a target from a view controller to the button that is created in a view (no action when it is pressed). But if I create the button in the view controller directly then it works.

What could be wrong here?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var mainView = MainView()
    var counter:Int = 0
    
    @objc func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!)
    {
        counter += 1
        print("Button was predded:\(counter)")
        mainView.lable1.text = "Button was predded:\(counter)"
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(mainView)
        mainView.buttno1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
    }
    
}


class MainView : UIView {
    
    var background: UIView = {
        return background
    }()
    
    lazy var buttno1: UIButton = {
        var btn = UIButton()
        ....
        
        return btn
    }()
    
    
    func createButton1(){
        print("Main view btn created")
        background.addSubview(buttno1)

    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.addSubview(background)
        createButton1()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the `createButton1` method being called at all? Also make sure you are setting proper frames for all of the subviews you are creating (or use constraints). The problem could be caused by the button being in a zero sized superview.

Comment: Thanks HangarRash , that was the problem, zero sized superview, this solved the problem: ```super.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)```